# Rails application - How to get TinyMCE to save a pasted image locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce

I am running into a very unique edge case with my TinyMCE user experience.

I want to be able to

1. COPY IMAGE (Right click, copy image on any image on the internet)
2. PASTE IMAGE (CTRL + V) into TinyMCE editor

and have it save a local copy of this image and serve that.

The problem is a user can paste an image being served in S3 bucket and it is only authenticated for a certain amount of time, then days later the image will not show.

I have looked at [TinyMCE - File Image Upload](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/file-image-upload/) documentation to no avail.

Also looked into [TinyMCE Paste Plugin](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/), [TinyMCE Local Upload Demo](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/demo/local-upload/), [TinyMCE Docs - Upload Images](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/upload-images/) and dated gem [TinyMCE-Rails-ImageUpload](https://github.com/PerfectlyNormal/tinymce-rails-imageupload)

Ultimately, I have a feeling that a custom handler for [Paste Preprocess](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/paste/#paste_preprocess) will need to be used

My tinymce.yml configuration follows:

```
menubar: false
statusbar: false
branding: false
toolbar:
  - styleselect | bold italic underline strikethrough | indent outdent | blockquote | image | link | codesample | bullist numlist | table | code | undo redo
plugins:
  - link
  - codesample
  - image
  - lists
  - code
  - table
images_upload_url: "/tinymce_assets"
automatic_uploads: true
relative_urls: false
remove_script_host: false
convert_urls: true
table_responsive_width: true
```

I feel like this type of problem should be common and there should be a simple solution that I am not seeing. However, if not at all possible, would the solution be to create a custom js function that intercepts paste call, check if it is coming from external url, then decide to create a local image copy and give that url?

Thank you, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since its available for sometime have you thought that may be the issue could be that authentication fails after some days and issue is really coming from s3?